# Is there a SQL Server Compact code generator that works with SQLite?

Tags: .net, sqlite, sql-server-ce

[SQL Compact Code Generator](http://sqlcecodegen.codeplex.com/documentation) is pretty nice to work with, it's a standalone GUI application for automatically generating a .NET data access layer code for objects in a SQL Server Compact Edition database.

I'd like to know if there is a similar program for working with non-compact SQlite (.sqlite database). Does anyone know?

Comment: Questions like this are specifically used as example to explain 'close reasons' . Please read what is on-topic here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, my free Visual Studio extension SQLite Toolbox includes code genration for the sqlite-net API

Comment: nice instructional video, too. Thanks Erik!